# Type Signatures in Haskell

Tags: haskell

My question is regarding Type Signatures.

The following code complies:

```
data Vector a = Vector a a a deriving (Show) 
vMult :: (Num a) => Vector a -> a -> Vector a 
(Vector i j k) `vMult` m = Vector (i*m) (j*m) (k*m)
```

However, I do not understand why substituting the above type signature (on line number 2) with the following ***does not*** work:

```
vMult :: (Num a) => Vector a -> Num -> Vector a
```

My understanding is that since `m` is of type `Num` (eg. the number `8`), and since `i, j, k` are `Num` as well, there should be no problems with computing `Vector (i*m) (j*m) (k*m)`.

Kindly correct my understanding.

Comment: Num is not a type, but a type class.  Understanding the difference between the two is key to understanding why the second signature is invalid.

Comment: Got it. I missed that point. Thanks a lot Thomas!

Answer (score 7):

### `Num a` isn't actually a type at all

`Num` is a type class, so if I say `Num a` it means `a` is a number type, so then

```
vMult :: (Num a) => Vector a -> a -> Vector a
```

means "as long as `a` is a number type, `vMult` takes a Vector of `a`s and a single `a` and returns a Vector of `a`s."

That means that `vMult` can work like
`vMult :: Vector Int -> Int -> Vector Int` or
`vMult :: Vector Double -> Double -> Vector Double`.
Notice you get each type by replacing all the `a`s in the original with a single number type.

### `Num` on it's own doesn't make sense

`Num` on its own would mean "is a number type", so if your function had the type signature

```
vMult :: (Num a) => Vector a -> Num -> Vector a
```

it would read "as long as `a` is a number type, `vMult` takes a Vector of `a`s and an is a number type and returns a Vector of `a`s." It's ungrammatical in English just the same as it's an error in Haskell.

It's like saying "give me some butter and a has a sharp edge" instead of "give me some butter and a knife". The type signature that worked is like saying "find something you can spread with (call it k), and give me some butter and k."

### Facts aren't types

You also can't use `Num a` instead of `a` like `Vector a -> Num a -> Vector a` because you can't put an assertion where you need a noun: "give me your key ring and a keys are made of metal so I can give you a new key ring".

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication is defined on `Num a` and `Num a` i.e. 2 arguments of same Type belonging to `Num` Typeclass.

```
(*) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

If you only have `Num` in your type signature, it would be akin to asking to allow multiplication to be done between say an `Integer` and `Float` because both are Types belonging to Typeclass `Num`. That is why you need to to specify the Type that should be used amd not just the `Typeclass`.

There is already a constraint to ensure that `a` should belong to `Num` when you use it for your `Vector`. In order to multiply each element in your `Vector` with the chosen scalar, that scalar must not only belong to `Num` but also be the same type i.e. `a`.

Comment: I don't see the sense in which it's like mixing different types. Do you mean there has to be an `a` so that you can express that all the types are the same? This is true, but you still can't use that signature if you put an `a` after the `Num`.

Comment: @AndrewC I realised that my answer earlier was misleading. I have edited it so that it makes more sense. Thanks for pointing out the flaws in it!

Answer (score 2):

`Num` is not a [concrete type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Concrete_data_type) that can be used there. It is a unary [type constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor) that must be specialized with another type to be used. Speaking in OOP terms, `Num` is not a OOP-like abstract "superclass" type to be derived from, it's rather a factory that must be specialized for its usage.

So, trying to pass `Num` to a place that requires [kind](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Kind) ("type" of a type) `*` is like trying to pass a function (`:: a -> b`) where a value (`:: c`) is required (the difference is that the former is done at type level):

```
ghci> :kind Int
Int :: *

ghci> :kind Num
Num :: * -> Constraint
```

so we can see that application of `Num` to any type of kind `*` at time of type-check produces kind `Constraint` and `Constraint` may only be used before `=>` in type signature (to limit what types are correct in position of `a` in `Vector a -> a -> Vector a`, that's the meaning of `Constraint`).

Comment: Technically it's correct that `Num` is a type constructor, but it's a bit confusing to say so, because it doesn't construct an actual Haskell type (that would be kind `* -> *` instead of `* -> Constraint`).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yep, I've edited out my initial misunderstanding that kind of `Num` is `* -> *`.